# How to generate 100Mpps traffic of 64B packet size with Pktgen?

Tags: lua, dpdk

I tried to use dpdk-pktgen 3.7.2 with dpdk 18.11, but it only reached about 35 Mpps traffic with 64B packet size.Following is my lua script:

```
package.path = package.path ..";?.lua;test/?.lua;app/?.lua;../?.lua"

require "Pktgen";

local time = 30;
local pcnt_rate = 100;

sendport = 0;
recvport = 1;
pkt_size = 64;
burst_cnt = 128
local dstip = "192.168.100.100";
local srcip = "192.168.0.0";

function main()
    pktgen.stop(sendport);
    sleep(2);

    pktgen.set(sendport, "size", burst_cnt);
    pktgen.set(sendport, "burst", 64);
    pktgen.set(sendport, "rate", pcnt_rate);
    pktgen.set_ipaddr(sendport, "dst", dstip);
    pktgen.set_ipaddr(sendport, "src", srcip);

    pktgen.set_proto(sendport..","..recvport, "udp");
    pktgen.start(sendport)

    sleep(time)
    pktgen.stop(sendport)
end

printf("\n**** Traffic Profile Rate for %d byte packets ***\n", pkt_size);
main();
printf("\n*** Traffic Profile Done (Total Time %d) ***\n", time);
```

l ran the script with the following command.

```
sudo pktgen -l 0-7 -n 4 -- -N -T -P -m "[1-7].0" -f script.lua
```

My NIC is Mellanox ConnectX-5 100GbE with traffic limit of 200Mpps and 100Gbps. Is there any problem in my script that restricts performance of pktgen? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking at bandwith used with or without overhead (i.e. size of package header)?

Comment: The code you show isn't C. What language is it? Why did you add the C tag? Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @SoliRaven  With 100Gbps interface one can theoretically reach 140Mpps with 60Byte packet, hence the expectation of `200Mps and 100Gbps` is quite confusing with 64B packet. I can reach up to 65Mpps with a single CPU thread using DPDK pktgen. Hence this looks like more of a configuration issue. Please update with CPU, Necessary Bios settings, Frequency, NUMA-Socket, and kernel cmdline to better understand,

Comment: @SoliRaven as mentioned in comments and answer one can generate up to 120 to 125 Mpps with Intel E810. Hence this looks more of configuration, platform or firmware issues. Can you please share your findings as it is not DPDk or Pktgen issue.

Comment: reply to `The code you show isn't C. What language is it? Why did you add the C tag? Also please take some time to read the help pages, take the SO tour, read How to Ask, as well as this question checklist. – 
Some programmer dude` the code snippet shared by @SoliRaven is lua script used by DPDK-Pktgen to configure and run test. Hence it is not C code. DPDK-PKTGEN is user space application written in C http://git.dpdk.org/apps/pktgen-dpdk/. Hence step to reproduce the error is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments this is more of configuration issue of platform or not choosing right platform. I am able to generate 120Mpps with 64B on 100Gbps (CVL NIC).

[EDIT-2] Finally got hands on Mellanox connectx6 DX cards (2 *100Gbps). With DPDK 21.11 and PKTGEN 21.11, it is possible to generate over 100MPPs

[image]

MLX PMD args used:  `mprq_en=1,rxqs_min_mprq=1,mprq_log_stride_num=9,txq_inline_mpw=128,rxq_pkt_pad_en=1`

Platform Details:

- DPDK:21.08
- PKTGEN:pktgen-dpdk-pktgen-21.03.1
- NIC:Ethernet Controller E810-C for QSFP
- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6152 CPU @ 2.10GHz
- PKTGEN CMD:`pktgen --legacy-mem -a 0000:86:00.0 -l 22-43   -- -P -m "[25-29:30-34].0" -N`

[image: Screen shot of pktgen page xstats]

[EDIT-1] @SoliRaven as mentioned in comments and answer one can generate up to 120 to 125 Mpps with Intel E810 & with Mellanox Connect6 DX 120MPPs. ***Hence this looks more like configuration, platform or firmware issues. Hence this is not DPDK or DPDK-PKTGEN is not issue.***